# How should i present a theory for a contradiction arise from current result?

Tags: publications, research-process

Currently i have almost finished my research in medical physics( Ms.c). We investigate a postulate and came with a contradiction. I have include all my result in the result and discussion section.  Duse to this contradiction i have investigated further and found some evidence.

But this new evidence and its principles were not included in the aim and the objective of the thesis. Because these new principles and finding arise from the previous findings.

Is it okey to explain the new principles and their physics in the result and discussion section? 
 or do i need to go back to the start and make my own hypothesis again?

Thanks
Manoj

Comment: For what to include in your Ms.c. thesis, ask your advisor.

Comment: The idea that you can't include information because it wasn't among the project's original aims seems absurd to me.  But maybe conventions are so different between medical physics and mathematics that what looks absurd to me is perfectly standard for you.  So I have to agree with @GEdgar that you need to ask your advisor.

Comment: In statistical studies it is easy to get bogus results by looking at the data first, then formulating your result.  Only the details of the situation could tell us whether this is one of those situations.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and it was a contradiction and included in my thesis, which led to start new research .